# Laravel: Use Memcache instead of Filesystem

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4, google-cloud-storage

Whenever I load a page, I can see Laravel reading a great amount of data from the /storage folder.

Generally speaking, dynamic reading and writing to our filesystem is a bottleneck. We are using Google App Engine and our storage is in Google Cloud Storage, which means that one write or read is equal to a "remote" API request. Google Cloud Storage is fast, but I feel it's slow, when Laravel makes up to 10-20 Cloud Storage calls per request.

Is it possible to store the data in the Memcache instead of in the /storage directory? I believe this will give our systems a lot better performance.

NB. Both Session and Cache uses Memcache, but compiled views and meta is stored on the filesystem.

Comment: It should be easier to just enable the opcode cache (if you're using PHP 5.5+) or install some opcode cache extension (e.g. XCache), if you're using older version. PHP files will be read once from disk and then read from memory in subsequent requests.

Comment: I am using 5.5, so and I have OPCache enabled. But since a file read is an API call, I'm sure OPCache does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Posting an answer right now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to store compiled views in **Memcache** you'd need to replace the storage that **Blade compiler** uses.

First of all, you'll need a new storage class that extends **Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem**. The methods that **BladeCompiler** uses are listed below - you'll need to make them use Memcache.

- exists
- lastModified
- get
- put

A draft of this class is below, you might want to make it more sophisticated:

```
class MemcacheStorage extends Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem {
  protected $memcached;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->memcached = new Memcached();
    $this->memcached->addServer(Config::get('view.memcached_host'), Config::get('view.memcached_port');
  }

  public function exists($key) {
    return !empty($this->get($key));
  }

  public function get($key) {
    $value = $this->memcached->get($key);
    return $value ? $value['content'] : null;
  }

  public function put($key, $value) {
    return $this->memcached->set($key, ['content' => $value, 'modified' => time()]);
  }

  public function lastModified($key) {
    $value = $this->memcached->get($key);
    return $value ? $value['modified'] : null;
  }
}
```

Second thing is adding memcache config in your **config/view.php**:

```
'memcached_host' => 'localhost',
'memcached_port' => 11211
```

Last thing you'll need to do is to overwrite **blade.compiler** service in one of your service providers, so that it uses your brand new memcached storage:

```
$app->singleton('blade.compiler', function ($app) {
    $cache = $app['config']['view.compiled'];

    $storage = $app->make(MemcacheStorage::class);

    return new BladeCompiler($storage, $cache);
});
```

That should do the trick.

Please let me know if you see some typos or error, haven't had a chance to run it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've registered the blade.compiler in the FilesystemServiceProvider. I can see it in compiled.php, but it still runs the old code and saves it on the Filesystem.

Comment: Add dd(get_class($files)); in BladeCompiler's constructor and paste what you get

Comment: I've done something, but I don't know what and now it works. Thanks :-)